# Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new' after upgrading to Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've just upgraded my app from Angular 9 to Angular 10 using the [official procedure](https://update.angular.io/) (with `ng update`) and after I did it, I got plenty of errors like:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Class constructor FormControl cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: can you please show us some code around the constructor call?

Comment: https://github.com/dirkluijk/ngx-typesafe-forms/blob/master/projects/ngx-typesafe-forms/src/lib/form-control.ts

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Could solve it by setting the `target` in `tsconfig.json` to `es2015`. Among other possible side effects, this means no more support for IE11. Hope this helps!

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
    },
```